# WebDriver not auto clearing after Geb + Spock specs

Tags: selenium, groovy, webdriver, spock, geb

When running multiple tests the driver was not auto clearing for a clean slate with new specs. How can I implement this functionality to clean the driver after each spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed a lot of questions for this problem but no one seems to point to a very easy built in solution.

Just put `autoClearWebStorage = true` in the `GebConfig.groovy` file. That is it!

[Link to documentation explaining how this is off by default here](https://gebish.org/manual/current/#auto-clearing-web-storage-configuration)

> Certain integrations will automatically clear the driver’s web
> storage, that is both local and session storage, which is usually
> necessary when using an implicit driver. This configuration flag,
> which is false by default, can be enabled by setting the
> autoClearWebStorage value in the config to true.
>
> `autoClearWebStorage = true`